# How to concatenate the second value to a String variable under For loop

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

The below for loop concatenate the previously fetched data, but while fetching the string value and performing the concatenation I get the value as **null**. Is there a better way to concatenate the string to the same String array variable.

```
for(int i=0;i<trs;i++) {  // 5
    List<WebElement> i2 = d.findElements(By.xpath("//*some/table/tr["+(i+1)+"]/td[2]/p"));
    int a=i2.size();
    for(int a1=1;a1<=a;a1++) {
        s1[i]+=d.findElement(By.xpath("//*some/table/tr["+(i+1)+"]/td[2]/p["+(a1)+"]")).getText().toString();                                                                                                                            
    }
}
```

The output for above code is like

- nullstring retrived;
- nullList item

i want better way to concat the above code

Comment: start with `s1[i] = ""`; just a guess since missing [mcve] actually above code has no output at all

Comment: Please post an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is unclear what is going on in your code (which does not compile).

Comment: before storing the value in to the array, did you tried to print out in the console using **system.out.print**. Whether it is printing the values in the console?

Comment: I did not print in console but i will input the values retrieved to text field with sendkeys(s1[i]) method

Comment: Whether the values are printing in console? just to confirm the values are retrieving properly

Comment: Yes.. it retrieves but Null is concatenated to the string.. S1[0] = "NullTask with chromebrowser"; s1[1]="NullTask with Selenium webdriver" and so on..